# Como suavizar aparecimento de div na galeria de imagens com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando uma galeria de imagens com filtro por categoria. Como faço para as imagens aparecerem mais lentamente quando filtradas? Segue código da página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Centralizar Site*/
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
}

/* Add padding entre as colunas */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Criando três colunas iguais lado a lado */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; 
}

/* Limpando float após as linhas */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Conteudo */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* A classe "show" é adicionada aos elementos filtrados */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* estilo dos botoes */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- MAIN -->
<div class="main">

<h1>Galeria com Filtro</h1>
<hr>


<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('geral')"> Geral</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('natureza')"> Natureza</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('carros')"> Carros</button>
</div>

<!-- Galeria -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column natureza">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447752875215-b2761acb3c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Mountains</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column natureza">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1426604966848-d7adac402bff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Lights</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column natureza">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431794062232-2a99a5431c6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Forest</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column carros">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557690891-d919fb7ecea9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Retro</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column carros">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577520413075-07f5bd4cbc62?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=871&q=80" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Fast</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column carros">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502877338535-766e1452684a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Classic</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  
<!-- FIM GRID -->
</div>

<!-- FIM MAIN -->
</div>

<script>
filterSelection("geral")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "geral") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar uma animação CSS para fazer fade-in. E de cada vez que filtras adicionas a classe da animação e fazes reset à animação.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Centralizar Site*/
.main {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
}

/* Add padding entre as colunas */
.row,
.row > .column {
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Criando três colunas iguais lado a lado */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; 
}

/* Limpando float após as linhas */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Conteudo */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* A classe "show" é adicionada aos elementos filtrados */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* estilo dos botoes */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

.fade-in-image {
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity:0;}
  100% {opacity:1;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- MAIN -->
<div class="main">

<h1>Galeria com Filtro</h1>
<hr>


<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('geral')"> Geral</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('natureza')"> Natureza</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('carros')"> Carros</button>
</div>

<!-- Galeria -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column natureza">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447752875215-b2761acb3c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Mountains</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column natureza">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1426604966848-d7adac402bff?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Lights</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column natureza">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431794062232-2a99a5431c6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Forest</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column carros">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557690891-d919fb7ecea9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Retro</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column carros">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577520413075-07f5bd4cbc62?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=871&q=80" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Fast</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column carros">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502877338535-766e1452684a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=872&q=80" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
      <h4>Classic</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  
<!-- FIM GRID -->
</div>

<!-- FIM MAIN -->
</div>

<script>
filterSelection("geral")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "geral") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "fade-in-image");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) {
        w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
        w3AddClass(x[i], "fade-in-image");
    }
  }
  resetAnimation();
}

function resetAnimation() {
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var el = x[i];
        el.style.animation = 'none';
        el.offsetHeight;
        el.style.animation = null;
    }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```